# blurring an image using PIL in python

Tags: image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pixel

I have been trying to blur an image using the PIL.

from what I know i need to copy the image, and then change every pixel to the average
of the pixels surrounding him, from the original picture. so I didn't get really far,
i'm using python 3.3x

```
from PIL import Image 

img = Image.open("source")
im = Image.copy(img)
```

I know how to use putpixe, and get a pixel's data, but I can't figure out how to get the
average of the pixels around.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 34):

You can just do:

```
blurred_image = original_image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

See the [ImageFilter](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html) module for more options.

You are correct in that the process you describe would blur the image, and there are filters that essentially directly do what you suggest (*e.g.", using the `ImageFilter.Kernel` method where you kernel has constant weights).  Using `ImageFilter` will be faster and easier though, and give you more options for blurring and beyond.

Comment: There is also ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=2) which is much better than ImageFilter.BLUR

Comment: When I do `blurred_image.show()` and try to save it it is saved as a bitmap file (.BMP). How can I change this to png or jpg?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Could ask this as a separate question; it's not really related to the original question.

Comment: @DavidG probably too late now to help you, but... `show()` uses a separate utility to show the image, and you're limited to whatever facilities it has built in.  Instead of `show()` you should use `save()` directly to let PIL save the file.