# Blur image with python

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to blur the image in the pwd and then save it to a new file:

```
from PIL import Image 
import glob, os

size = 128, 128
from PIL import ImageFilter

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    print "processing %s\n" % infile
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    print " file %s, extension %s\n" % (file, ext)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    #im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #im.save(file + "thumb", "JPEG")
    im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
    im.save(file + "blurred2", "JPEG")
```

What's saved looks exactly like the original image, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the filtered image to a new image.

```
im1 = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

Code example:

```
import ImageFilter

def filterBlur(im):

    im1 = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)

    im1.save("BLUR" + ext)

filterBlur(im1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
blurred_image = original_image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

See [image filter modules](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html) for more works ..:)

i would recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215903/blurring-an-image-using-pil-in-python).