# It's possible to create a blurred text with reportlab?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to reproduce a blurred/text-shadow effect using reportlab. Something like this.

[image]

So far my approach was to work with the filling color (the text itself or the background), but I don't think I'm going to be successful if I follow this path because the `class` only accepts an opacity (`alpha`) paramater besides the ones that defines the color itself. Now I'm trying to find some font that will mimic this effect.

So, It's possible to reproduce the desirable effect with `reportlab`? If yes, which approach should I use to achieve it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any straightforward way to achieve a blurry effect as you [can achieve with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/) or even with the [PIL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215903/blurring-an-image-using-pil-in-python) using [reportlab](https://pypi.org/project/reportlab/).

You can try one of the following fonts that more-less mimic this effect: [Acidic](https://www.dafont.com/acidic.font), [ExtraBlur](https://www.dafont.com/extrablur.font), [Erthqake Font](https://www.1001fonts.com/erthqake-font.html), [Static Buzz Font](https://www.1001fonts.com/static-buzz-font.html#character-map)
, [vtks trunkset Font](https://www.1001fonts.com/vtks-trunkset-font.html#character-map) and use the `pdfmetrics.registerFont()` and `TTFont()` methods (e.g. using the Static Buzz Font):

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

canvas = Canvas('temp.pdf')
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('StaticBuzz', '/path/to/TTF-file/StaticBuzz.ttf')) #Change the path to the .ttf file.
canvas.setFont('StaticBuzz', 32)
canvas.drawString(0, 700, "Sample usage of StaticBuzz Font.")
canvas.save()
```

Comment: Yep, I'm going thorugh this direction (with a slightly different font from the ones you suggested). Unfortunately isn't the solution I was hoping but it will handle for now :). Thanks for the response!

Comment: Sadly, it's not possible using merely any attribute from a reportlab class.

Answer (score 4):

If it is an option (free standing text / headline), you could transform the text to a picture first and then blur it using the PIL library.

The filter can be adapted by setting `radius` so a strong blur effect can be achieved:

[image: before]
[image: after]

```
from PIL import ImageFilter
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('test.png')

blurred_img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=5))
blurred_img.show()
```

Comment: Transform the text to a picture is not an option, unfortunately. But thanks for your answer!